# Why is Latex not writing all my bibliography references?

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I've been writing a paper with BibTex bibliography but suddenly the .tex stop writing all the references I have in the .bib file, they are 15 cites (all used) and it only writes 9, why is so? Whay am I missing? Thanks

Here's the code I have in the .tex file:

```
\newpage
\bibliography{Bibliografia_1}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía}
```

And these are my references:

```
@article{WHODiabetes,
  title={Diabetes},
  author={Organización Mundial de la Salud},
  journal={World Health Organization},
  year={2015},
  publisher={World Health ORganization}
}


@article{DiabetesFMD,
  title={Diferentes tipos de diabetes y sus tratamientos},
  author={Fundación Mexicana de Diabetes, A.C.},
  journal={Fundación Mexicana de Diabetes, A.C.},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Fundación Mexicana de Diabetes, A.C.}
}

@article{AtlasIDF,
  title={IDF Diabetes Atlas, Sixth Edition},
  author={International Diabetes Federation},
  journal={International Diabetes Federation},
  number={6},
  year={2014},
  publisher={International Diabetes Federation}
}


@book{GlucosiladaBD,
  title={Hemoglobina Glucosilada... La Prueba de la Verdad},
  author={BD},
  volume={},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Centro de Aprendizaje BD}
}

@article{tratamiento,
  title={Recomendaciones para el tratamiento farmacol{\'o}gico de la hiperglucemia en la diabetes tipo 2},
  author={Torre, E Men{\'e}ndez and Tejedor, J Lafita and Men{\'e}ndez, S Artola and N{\'u}{\~n}ezfiCort{\'e}s, J Mill{\'a}n and Garc{\'\i}a, A Alonso and Domingo, M Puig and Solans, JR Garc{\'\i}a and Guisasola, F {\'A}lvarez and Alegr{\'\i}a, J Garc{\'\i}a and Bravo, J Mediavilla and others},
  journal={Avances en diabetolog{\'\i}a},
  volume={26},
  number={5},
  pages={331--338},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Elsevier Doyma}
}


@article{bergman1979,
  title={Quantitative estimation of insulin sensitivity.},
  author={Bergman, Richard N and Ider, Y Ziya and Bowden, CHARLES R and Cobelli, Claudio},
  journal={American Journal of Physiology-Endocrinology And Metabolism},
  volume={236},
  number={6},
  pages={E667},
  year={1979},
  publisher={Am Physiological Soc}
}
@article{bergman1981,
  title={Physiologic evaluation of factors controlling glucose tolerance in man: measurement of insulin sensitivity and beta-cell glucose sensitivity from the response to intravenous glucose.},
  author={Bergman, Richard N and Phillips, Lawrence S and Cobelli, Claudio},
  journal={Journal of Clinical Investigation},
  volume={68},
  number={6},
  pages={1456},
  year={1981},
  publisher={American Society for Clinical Investigation}
}
@article{hovorka2002,
  title={Partitioning glucose distribution/transport, disposal, and endogenous production during IVGTT},
  author={Hovorka, Roman and Shojaee-Moradie, Fariba and Carroll, Paul V and Chassin, Ludovic J and Gowrie, Ian J and Jackson, Nicola C and Tudor, Romulus S and Umpleby, A Margot and Jones, Richard H},
  journal={American Journal of Physiology-Endocrinology and Metabolism},
  volume={282},
  number={5},
  pages={E992--E1007},
  year={2002},
  publisher={Am Physiological Soc}
}
@article{hovorka2004,
  title={Nonlinear model predictive control of glucose concentration in subjects with type 1 diabetes},
  author={Hovorka, Roman and Canonico, Valentina and Chassin, Ludovic J and Haueter, Ulrich and Massi-Benedetti, Massimo and Federici, Marco Orsini and Pieber, Thomas R and Schaller, Helga C and Schaupp, Lukas and Vering, Thomas and others},
  journal={Physiological measurement},
  volume={25},
  number={4},
  pages={905},
  year={2004},
  publisher={IOP Publishing}
}
@phdthesis{sorensen1985,
  title={A physiologic model of glucose metabolism in man and its use to design and assess improved insulin therapies for diabetes},
  author={Sorensen, John Thomas},
  year={1985},
  school={Massachusetts Institute of Technology}
}
@article{quiroz2007,
  title={On hyperglicemic glucose basal levels in Type 1 Diabetes Mellitus from dynamic analysis},
  author={Quiroz, G and Femat, R},
  journal={Mathematical biosciences},
  volume={210},
  number={2},
  pages={554--575},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{man2007meal,
  title={Meal simulation model of the glucose-insulin system},
  author={Man, Chiara Dalla and Rizza, Robert and Cobelli, Claudio and others},
  journal={Biomedical Engineering, IEEE Transactions on},
  volume={54},
  number={10},
  pages={1740--1749},
  year={2007},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
@article{cobelli2009,
  title={In silico preclinical trials: a proof of concept in closed-loop control of type 1 diabetes},
  author={Kovatchev, Boris P and Breton, Marc and Dalla Man, Chiara and Cobelli, Claudio},
  journal={Journal of diabetes science and technology},
  volume={3},
  number={1},
  pages={44--55},
  year={2009},
  publisher={SAGE Publications}
}


@incollection{regierer2013future,
  title={Future of medicine: models in predictive diagnostics and personalized medicine},
  author={Regierer, Babette and Zazzu, Valeria and Sudbrak, Ralf and K{\"u}hn, Alexander and Lehrach, Hans and ITFoM Consortium and others},
  booktitle={Molecular Diagnostics},
  pages={15--33},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@article{kitano2002systems,
  title={Systems biology: a brief overview},
  author={Kitano, Hiroaki},
  journal={Science},
  volume={295},
  number={5560},
  pages={1662--1664},
  year={2002},
  publisher={American Association for the Advancement of Science}
}
```

Comment: Are all the references cited in your work?

Comment: It works for me.
Try running pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex.

Comment: Apparently you have to separate accounts. Contact the StackExchange Staff in order to get them merged